# dynamic names does not work in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use dynamic  name to animation between fade and slide in vuejs, but it doesn't seem to work. The code is pasted below  the animation option does not change upon switching in the value of the select tags.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @click="show = !show">Show Alert</button>                
          <select v-model="alertAnimation" class="form-control my-4">
            <option value="slide">slide</option>
            <option value="fade">fade</option>
          </select>
```

here's the script

```
    data() {
            return {
              show: false,
              alertAnimation:'fade',
            }
        }
```

here's the style

```
    .fade-enter{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .fade-enter-active{
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
  }
  .fade-leave{

  }
  .fade-leave-active{
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .slide-enter{
  }
  .slide-enter-active{
    animation: slide-in 1s ease-out forwards;

  }
  .slide-leave{

  }
  .slide-leave-active{
    animation: slide-out 1s ease-out forwards;
  }
  @keyframes slide-in {
    from{
      transform: translateY(20px);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to{
      transform: translateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  @keyframes slide-out {
    from{
      transform: translateY(0);

    }
    to{
      transform: translateY(20px);
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you trying to achieve? [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVwXgO)

> Example with slide and fade transitions

```
<div id="app">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="show = !show">Show Alert</button>                
   <select v-model="alertAnimation" class="form-control my-4">
      <option value="slide">slide</option>
      <option value="fade">fade</option>
   </select>
   <div>
      <div id="app">
         <transition :name="alertAnimation" mode="out-in">
            <h1 v-if="show" key="1">Panel 1</h1>
            <h1 v-if="!show"key="2">Panel 2</h1>
         </transition>
         <transition :name="alertAnimation" mode="out-in">
            <div v-if="show" key="1">
               panel 1
               <a href="#" @click.prevent="show = false">
               Go to the panel 2
               </a>
            </div>
            <div v-if="!show" key="2">
               panel 2
               <a href="#" @click.prevent="show = true">
               &lt; Go back to panel 1
               </a>
            </div>
         </transition>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```